# Disposing of data added in DataTable using button clicks

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I am looking for a way to dispose of a data that I added in a DataTable using a button click.
Here is the code for the DataTable

```
private DataTable ReadExcel(string fileName, string fileExt)
    {
        string conn = string.Empty;
        DataTable dtexcel = new DataTable();
        if (fileExt.CompareTo(".xls") == 0)
        {
            conn = @"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HRD=Yes;IMEX=1';"; //for below excel 2007  
        }
        else
            conn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=NO';"; //for above excel 2007  
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conn))
        {

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                OleDbDataAdapter oleAdpt = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", con); //here we read data from sheet1                           
                oleAdpt.Fill(dtexcel); //fill excel data into dataTable
                con.Dispose();
            }
            catch { }
        }
        return dtexcel;
    }
```

And this is how the button currently works:

```
private void loadFileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = string.Empty;
        string fileExt = string.Empty;
        OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog(); //open dialog to choose file  
        if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) //if there is a file choosen by the user  
        {
            filePath = file.FileName; //get the path of the file  
            fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filePath); //get the file extension  
            loadFilePath.Text = filePath; //display the path to the file in the loadFile text box
            if (fileExt.CompareTo(".xls") == 0 || fileExt.CompareTo(".xlsx") == 0)
            {
                try
                {                      
                    this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
                    dataGridView1.VirtualMode = true;                       
                    dataGridView1.Visible = true;
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = ReadExcel(filePath, fileExt);                    
                    this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
                    MessageBox.Show("File loaded successfully!", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK); //custom message for successful file loading
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please choose .xls or .xlsx file only.", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error); //custom messageBox to show error  
            }
        }           
    }
```

The program and the code works perfectly fine, but the problem lies in the data which is already inside the DataTable() and I can't seem to find a way to dispose of it. In my clear button, I use the following line `this.dataGridView1.DataSource = null;` but this only clears the data already inserted in the dataGridView. Please help me with this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `this.dataGridView1.DataSource = null;` should work. What you mean by _ but the problem lies in the data which is already inside the DataTable() and I can't seem to find a way to dispose of it_? You have only one `DataTable` which created in `ReadExcel`. How you see that data wasn't "disposed"?

Comment: Once I load the file inside the program, when I click the clear button, the data still stays in the DataTable and I need to get rid of it so I can add new data on another button click. I see the data not being disposed in the task manager and the physical memory used by the program.

Comment: .NET is managed memory framework, GarbageCollector will free all reserved memory when needed. Usually with small or middle sized applications Garbage collector will free memory only after application closes. You don't need to worry about this - just call `ReadExcel` so much as you want.

Comment: Just notice on your code: remove `try .. catch` and `con.Dispose()`. `try .. catch` is useless because you do nothing in `catch` and `con.Dispose` is redundant because `using` block will call `con.Dispose()` method when execution goes outside of it.

Comment: Thank you for the advises, I really appreciate the help with my problem. Thank you again for the help.